# How do I create and indent "preamble" sections in algorithms?

Tags: algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` to write algorithms. I'm doing things in such a way that, before the actual algorithm, I have a section for input and output arguments, and when relevant, references to other algorithms and equations that may be far away in the document. Like so:

[image: This is rendering properly]

I have introduced the "preamble" section of references with `\SetKwInput{KwRef}{Referências}`. So far so good.

But the way I'm doing it seems not to be the most clever way. I'm using `\quad` at the beginning of every item:

```
\begin{algorithm}
        \caption{My example}
        \KwIn{\\
            \quad$X$: something\\
            \quad$Y$: something else
        }
        \KwOut{\\
            \quad$R$: the result
        }
        \KwRef{\\
            \quad$f(\cdot)$ is the function introduced in Equation~\ref{eq:znorm}
        }
        $R \leftarrow X + Y$\;
    \end{algorithm}
```

What's the smart way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead perform the placement of `\quad` automatically via a `tabular`; this seems to fit in with your current usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\KwIn}[1]{%
  \KwIna{\strut\\ \quad\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\renewcommand{\KwOut}[1]{%
  \KwOuta{\strut\\ \quad\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\KwRef}[1]{%
  \KwRefa{\strut\\ \quad\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\SetKwInput{KwIna}{Parâmetros de Entrada}
\SetKwInput{KwOuta}{Parâmetros de Saída}
\SetKwInput{KwRefa}{Referências}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My example}
  \KwIn{%
    $X$: something \\
    $Y$: something else
  }
  \KwOut{%
    $R$: the result
  }
  \KwRef{%
    $f(\cdot)$ is the function introduced in Equation~\ref{eq:znorm}
  }
  $R \leftarrow X + Y$\;
\end{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{2.3}% Just for this example
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:znorm}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but... how?

Comment: The argument supplied to `\KwIn` (and friends) is placed inside a `tabular`. Using ``\\`` to line-break the content translates well to the `tabular` environment. Each command inserts ``\\``, followed by a `\quad` and the `tabular`. The `tabular` sets its content `l`eft aligned (without a prepended space, due to `@{}`).

Comment: Ah, so maybe what you actually meant is that I could automatically add a `\quad` and insert the lines into a `tabular`? I was thinking that somehow this command was inserting several `\quad`s: one for each line of the tabular environment.